# How to correctly set up routes when creating a new view in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapping, routes

I created a new action called "asked". asked.haml is in views/questions as it should be. I've also added

```
  def asked
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.xml  { render :xml => @questions }
    end
  end
```

to the Questions controller for this action.

My problem is that when I got to the url http://localhost:3000/questions/asked, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in QuestionsController#show

Couldn't find Question with ID=asked
```

So, I Googled this and found out that I needed to change the way I route things.

I tried: `map.connect ':controller/asked', :action => 'asked'` and `map.resources :questions, :collection => {:asked => :get}`, but to no avail.

Obviously I don't fully understand how Rails mapping works, but if someone would let me know what's going on, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails routing works by picking the *first* route that matches the requested URL.

From your description it seems that you put your `map.connect` statements to the bottom of your `routes.rb`.  You should place it before `map.resources :questions`, since otherwise the URL `/questions/asked` is matched by `map.resources` as a `show` action.